# Can I move all DB files on SQL server 2008 to a different logical drive and then change the drive letter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a SQL Server 2008 (std) with 19 DBs.  Because I'm replacing my SAN, I need to move all the DB files to a different volume.  I've moved individual DBs before using MS's recommended method:  detach DB, move files, reattach.  But I really don't want to do that in this case, partially out of lazyness, but also because some of the DBs belong to SharePoint and have a bunch of hex at the end of the name, which could potentially get messed up.

So my idea is to shut down the SQL server services, move all the files at once, dismount the old volume, and change the drive letter of the new volume to that of the old one.

Would this work?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you proposed will work, assuming that you use the same folder structure as existed on the old data drive.

Comment: Thanks.  In your opinion, would this be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: +1 for this method. I've this many, many times. The only thing is that you want to be sure to copy the security ACLs for the files and folders onto the new drive as well or the server may not be able to open the files.

Comment: Yes, that is the easiest way to do it.  Personally I'd use Robocopy to just duplicate the structure, including the "/SEC" switch to copy security ACL's.